# Merge rows of multiple columns into one (row) R

Tags: r, merge, plyr

I have a data like this and would like to merge them into one row. Certainly I can do a for loop, but this is not elegant and in efficient.
My current data:

```
0.063456491   0.004457746    0.013450942     0.023948062     0.02247313
0.003147881  -0.018681539   -0.009495686    -0.008677241     0.013863377
0.083954841   0.100283809    0.061790913    -0.004592628    -0.052269582
-0.021375194  -0.041536406  -0.044538945     0.023639958     0.037451282
```

Expected output:

```
0.063456491 0.004457746 0.013450942 0.023948062 0.02247313  0.003147881 -0.018681539    -0.009495686    -0.008677241    0.013863377 0.083954841 0.100283809 …
```

Many thanks,
Phuong

Comment: assuming the data you show is in a matrix form: `as.vector(df)`

Comment: something like `data.frame(t(unlist(df)))` ?

Comment: @Ronak: thanks very much, it works and as I expected when adding another step like this:
df1<-data.frame(unlist(df))
df2<-data.frame(t(df1),row.names = NULL)

Comment: @Omry: I did not show any changes when applying as.vector(), but thanks anyway

Comment: why do you need 2 steps? `data.frame(t(unlist(df)))` gives you the same output?

Comment: Hi Ronak: I just checked carefully, the output is not expected. Can you look back my question again: What I wanted was to take row 2 to paste in row 1, then row 3 paste in (1+2) and so on. This unlist() transpose columns by columns, which was not my desire.
It looks like transpose a group of 5 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your data is numeric and you want to extract it row-wise you could do

```
data.frame(t(as.numeric(t(df))))

#          X1          X2         X3         X4         X5          X6 ......
#1 0.06345649 0.004457746 0.01345094 0.02394806 0.02247313 0.003147881 ......
```

Or a more general `as.vector` approach would also work

```
data.frame(t(as.vector(t(df))))
```

Answer (score 1):

use function unlist to merge all into one row

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(0.0000,0.1111,0.2222), v2 = c(1.11111,1.22222,1.33333))
 print(df)
      v1      v2
1 0.0000 1.11111
2 0.1111 1.22222
3 0.2222 1.33333
> df <- unlist (df, use.names = F)
> print(df)
 0.00000 0.11110 0.22220 1.11111 1.22222 1.33333
```

Comment: Actually, the output I want is: 0.0000 1.11111 0.1111 1.22222 0.2222 1.33333